# GetPointAtFractionLength - how to check if path is correct

Tags: wpf, path, geometry, pathgeometry

I was wondering if there is any way to check the validity of an object of `PathGeometry`.

I need to use `GetPointAtFractionLength` to get some point at the path, however for some paths this function throws an exception:

`Value does not fall within the expected range`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to check if the pathGeometry is valid, as you're looking for a point on that path based on it's length.  Unless you're passing a "progress" that is outside of the range of the path I'm lost.  Just remember that if the "progress" is larger than 100% you'll have problems.

Comment: Can you clarify your issue a bit more?  Perhaps an example.

Comment: I'm getting this occasionally from remote exception logging so I don't have a repro at present. I'm passing 0.5 as the fraction, so the problem must be the path. I know this question is 4 years old but it's the only hit I got on google for this problem so I thought I should pitch in.

Comment: Update: Geometries with zero-length paths will throw this exception if GetPointAtFractionLength() is called on them.